# SEO traffic dropped suddenly

Tags: seo, google-search-console

My website was doing relatively very well in terms of SEO,
I was getting around 10 000 page impressions and more than a few thousand clicks per day for keywords that other than my brand name. Keywords such as "Hard Food", "pre-cum" and some drug names.

And then one day I witnessed a sudden drop and since then I'm only stuck with a maximum of 1000 impressions per day and a few hundred clicks only for my brand name.

My SEO score on WooRank is around 70%, my page load speed is 93% (according to GTMetrix, ySlow).

The website didn't change, the only thing that might have changed was that we stopped the Google Ads.

Is there anything I should consider? or maybe I'm looking for the wrong type of optimizations.

Let me know if you need other info!

Comment: There's no way anyone can know what happened. Based on the timing and what you wrote you *probably* got hit by the [Penguin algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin). Google has said a lot about it. Research it and go from there. FTI, woorank is meaningless and page speed is just a tiny part of a page's ranking.

Comment: Panguin Tool can be useful in analyzing these kinds of problems, since it sounds like you were a victim of Google's search algorithm change: http://www.barracuda-digital.co.uk/panguin-tool/#